# This branch is 1 commit ahead, 2 commits behind main

Tags: git, github

I pushed all the changes to branch and then performed pull and merged into main. Then accidentally I pushed again xcuserdata/ files into main. when I checkout my branch I had to stash the xcuserdata file and branch is up to date with origin/branch. But when I checkout main I see the main code has gone back to older version of my code. How do I bring my main to the same as branch. Otherwise I will not see  my branch changes in main

```
% git log --oneline --graph --decorate main origin/main r2nr/r2nr.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/vhrao.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
* d42e9da (origin/main, main) Ignore some files
* 429d79a coredata to cloudkit works across two phones and two different cloud accounts but still exports data from one user to other user
* f737f3b Reset CloudKit dev environment and code to successfully sync and export Core data to CloudKit
* 34354cd crated Coredata entity LocationInfra and code to save it along with Location
*   3694149 Added Core Data to CloudKit synchronization for public database functionality
|\  
| * d9922fc Added Core Data to CloudKit synchronization for public database functionality
* | fd94fe0 added Firebase API message notification code in AppDelegate
|/  
* 290e343 Removed .DS_Store from all directories
* 1d529fd  added code to track and get a list of apartment units at a given location
*   a328e0a  merged to main
|\  
| * 0307a07  fixed bugs in add location and calculator
| * 38dc5c4 xcuserstate
| * 4461edc corrections to stage characters in source code
| * 22cbcb3 xcode files
* | 6c9d4cf xcuserstate
* | 5b30dbf xcuserstate
* | ccb9ae3 changes
|/  
* cd7e27b Add location - If address is outside Texas then API will be called with user input
* 27faa5b fixed add location- verified creating iCloud records and linking provider to location
* 5f7c041 Fixed ESID lookup in Add Location
* 0284d6d fixed bugs in location ID while adding load or capacity via LoadAndCapacityTableViewController, after selecting a row from end point profile
* f90bb38 uncommented code in profilemapviewcontroller
* 2416a04 uncommented code for Details button on profilemapviewcontroller
* ec34a1c Added apartment option to household
* 6d8ac7e second commit of full code


git log --oneline --graph --decorate main origin/main r2nr/r2nr.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/vhrao.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
* d42e9da (origin/main, main) Ignore some files
* 429d79a coredata to cloudkit works across two phones and two different cloud accounts but still exports data from one user to other user
* f737f3b Reset CloudKit dev environment and code to successfully sync and export Core data to CloudKit
* 34354cd crated Coredata entity LocationInfra and code to save it along with Location
*   3694149 Added Core Data to CloudKit synchronization for public database functionality
|\  
| * d9922fc Added Core Data to CloudKit synchronization for public database functionality
* | fd94fe0 added Firebase API message notification code in AppDelegate
|/  
* 290e343 Removed .DS_Store from all directories
* 1d529fd  added code to track and get a list of apartment units at a given location
* 0307a07  fixed bugs in add location and calculator
* 22cbcb3 xcode files
* cd7e27b Add location - If address is outside Texas then API will be called with user input
* 27faa5b fixed add location- verified creating iCloud records and linking provider to location
* 5f7c041 Fixed ESID lookup in Add Location
* 0284d6d fixed bugs in location ID while adding load or capacity via LoadAndCapacityTableViewController, after selecting a row from end point profile
* 2416a04 uncommented code for Details button on profilemapviewcontroller
* ec34a1c Added apartment option to household
* 6d8ac7e second commit of full code

% git log --oneline --graph --decorate main origin/branch02_vr                                                            
* d42e9da (origin/main, main) Ignore some files
*   dc617ba Merge pull request #4 from vihrao/branch02_vr
|\  
| | * 18202e1 (HEAD -> branch02_vr, origin/branch02_vr) Added Firebase Integration
| |/  
| * 2520ef3 Added Firebase Integration
|/  
* 429d79a coredata to cloudkit works across two phones and two different cloud accounts but still exports data from one user to other user
* f737f3b Reset CloudKit dev environment and code to successfully sync and export Core data to CloudKit
* 34354cd crated Coredata entity LocationInfra and code to save it along with Location
*   3694149 Added Core Data to CloudKit synchronization for public database functionality
|\  
| * d9922fc Added Core Data to CloudKit synchronization for public database functionality
* | fd94fe0 added Firebase API message notification code in AppDelegate
|/  
* 290e343 Removed .DS_Store from all directories
* 1d529fd  added code to track and get a list of apartment units at a given location
*   a328e0a  merged to main
|\  
| * 0307a07  fixed bugs in add location and calculator
| * 798f467 Added .gitignore file to contain xcuserdata/ dir that overlooks both UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate and Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
| * 38dc5c4 xcuserstate
| * 4461edc corrections to stage characters in source code
| * 22cbcb3 xcode files
| * b48b81c removed junk charecters from code
* | 6c9d4cf xcuserstate
* | 5b30dbf xcuserstate
* | 76f8244 corrections to stage characters in source code
* | ccb9ae3 changes
|/  
* cd7e27b Add location - If address is outside Texas then API will be called with user input
* 27faa5b fixed add location- verified creating iCloud records and linking provider to location
* 5f7c041 Fixed ESID lookup in Add Location
* 78daa78 fixed ESID look up in Add Location TableView Controller
* 0284d6d fixed bugs in location ID while adding load or capacity via LoadAndCapacityTableViewController, after selecting a row from end point profile
*   dd5bfe5 (origin/branch091922_vr) Merge pull request #3 from vihrao/branch02_ed
|\  
| * d5e1879 (origin/branch02_ed) endPtSearch
* | 4c77e77 Merge pull request #2 from vihrao/branch02_ed
|\| 
| * 822fcf9 UI Changes
* | 9baaa9c Merge pull request #1 from vihrao/branch02_ed
|\| 
| * 9da5e89 ProviderPlanTVC
|/  
* f90bb38 uncommented code in profilemapviewcontroller
* 2416a04 uncommented code for Details button on profilemapviewcontroller
* ec34a1c Added apartment option to household
* f3bffd9 (origin/branch01_vr) changes to README.md
* 6d8ac7e second commit of full code
* 8e9d5f1 first commit
(END)
```

Comment: Please include the first few lines of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate main origin/main xcuserdata` by [edit]ing your question

Comment: I have edited the question with log details. It was not the entire xcuserdata/ . I think it was two file that I had an issue with as edited above

Comment: Thanks for extending the question. I thought that `xcuserdata` was a branch as well. According to your output, `main` and `origin/main` both point to the same commit; none of the branches is ahead of behind the other. What is your _current_ branch?

Comment: % git branch
* branch02_vr
  main
My current branch is branch02_vr

Comment: Please include `branch02_vr` in the ref list of the log command (and remove the file/directory names)

Comment: added branch02_vr in the log statement. Please note that branch02_ed was from another contributor who has been removed from my repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit `18202e1` only exists in branches `branch02_vr` and `origin/branch02_vr`, but not in `main` nor `origin/main`.

Depending on what you want achieve, you should merge `branch02_vr` into `main` or `main` into `branch_02_vr`. Afterwards, you'd possibly want to fast-forward the respective other branch:

```
git checkout main
git merge branch02_vr
```

To fast-forward your `branch02_vr` branch, use:

```
git push . main:branch02_vr
# or: git checkout branch02_vr && git merge main
```

Don't forget to push so that your remote repository and its remote-tracking branches (`origin/...`) are updated.

Comment: commit 18202e1 is all where I have lot of changes that need to be pushed into main. So I want to merge branch02_vr into main and overwrite it right? So what is the correct command sequence?can you please give me without the OR clause

Comment: I have already shown the command sequence to get the changes of `branch02_vr` into branch `main`.

Comment: little scared so I dont want to overwrite my branch, instead overwrite my main with branch. I would use git checkout main
git merge branch02_vr git push . main:branch02_vr git push

Comment: @vrao branches are always ephemeral. What counts are commits. Commits are immutable and stored in your object database. If you don't want to change `branch02_vr`, don't push into it and only merge it to master. It solely depends whether you want `main` in `branch02_vr` too, or only `branch02_vr` in `main`.

Comment: I am confused with your statements look little difficult for me to understand. I want my changes from branch02_into main. So command sequence would be 
git checkout main
git merge branch02_vr
what does this do?  git push . main:branch02_vr
At the end you says again don't forget to push what is that?

Comment: @vrao `git checkout main; git merge branch02_vr` merges `branch02_vr` _into_ main. `git push . main:branch02_vr` does the opposite: it merges `main` into `branch02_vr` (fast-forwards `branch02_vr` to `main`). "Don't forget to push": you have `origin`, so you have a remote repository. You want to push your updated local branches to your remote repository, otherwise your remote and your local repository will be out-of-sync again.

Comment: % git merge branch02_vr
warning: Cannot merge binary files: …./UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate (HEAD vs. branch02_vr)
Auto-merging r…./UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in …./UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
Auto-merging …./Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in …../Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
How to fix the conflict?

Comment: @vrao like any other conflict of a binary file: pick the correct version of the file (from `main` or from `branch02_vr`) or regenerate the file if possible.

Comment: Yes I picked the local version for conflicts and merged, git pushed on both main and branch and they are up to date now. Thank you